# Is Windows 7 Administrator user meant to be activated?

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, user-accounts, administrator

I just started to work on a Windows 7 Environment for one of our products which is, until now, still shipped with Windows XP.

Now my question: The customer only has access to a very restricted system, but we need admin access sometimes.
Should I create another, admin privileged user or is it okay to enable the Windows 7 Administrator user?

Thanks,
Wolle

Comment: It is better to create another Administrator Account with Password.

Comment: In my opinion it should be :-)  In the situation mentioned with customers that you do not know the skill level of, I wonder if this "sometimes" access could be done with a Run_As instead?  privelage for the needed program operation only? There are a lot of safties in place for the restricted accounts, that are probably more useful to the manager of whatever systems your involved with other people using.  Setting up the system with full control, if you can control it all , works for me, but if you cannot control what they do, then probably not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Administrator account is disabled for a reason. It has been flagged as a security risk to have the administrator account be named Administrator. Its better to create a new user with admin privileges.

Temporarily enabling it and then disabling it is considered okay though.